# Is there a way to lock the horizontal scroll in safari on ipad?

Tags: javascript, html, mobile-safari, viewport, meta-tags

Does anybody know if there is a way to lock the horizontal scroll in safari on ipad using javascript/css/html?

I have the following meta tag in place in an attempt to fix the viewport

```
<!--  Mobile viewport -->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is interested, I managed to solve this problem by adding

```
event.stopPropagation();
event.preventDefault();
```

to the touchmove event.